# How to read .epub or .mobi file in Instapaper?

Tags: instapaper

Is there a way to read an Epub or Mobi file file in Instapaper?

Answer (score -1):

Try https://instapaper.com/epub and https://instapaper.com/mobi

ePub unfortunately generates lots of errors
Mobi page is not responding

Comment: I'm confused.  Your second sentence sounds like a reason NOT to Try them.